# Form 'Submit' button not working in IE

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have an inquiry form that works in Chrome and Firefox, but the submit button doesn't want to work in IE.
It allows me to enter any information in the text boxes and the rest of the functionality seems to be fine, it's just the submit button that won't give me a call back.

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9X9pX/)**

```
<div class="form">
    <form id="form" action="" method="post">
        <div class="div_input">
            <input type="text" name="c_name" value="Name" onfocus="if(this.value=='Name')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Name';" />
        </div>
        <div class="div_input">
            <input type="text" name="c_email" value="E-mail" onfocus="if(this.value=='E-mail')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='E-mail';" />
        </div>
        <div class="div_input">
            <input type="text" name="c_tel" value="Telephone" onfocus="if(this.value=='Telephone')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Telephone';" />
        </div>
        <div class="div_textarea">
            <textarea name="c_text" rows="1" cols="1" onfocus="if(this.value=='Text')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Text';">Text</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="div_btn">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="c_send" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="div_warnings"></div>
        <div class="loading">
            <img src="" alt="Loading" />
        </div>
        <div class="alert">
            <img src="" alt="Loading" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>
</div>

<? php
/*
 * Ajax form submit
 */

#request sent using HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['c_name']) AND isset($_POST['c_email']) AND isset($_POST['c_tel']) AND isset($_POST['c_text'])) {
        $to = 'coryjharris1@gmail.com';

        $name = filter_var($_POST['c_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $email = filter_var($_POST['c_email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $telephone = filter_var($_POST['c_tel'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $message = filter_var($_POST['c_text'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $sent = email($to, $email, $name, $telephone, $message);
        if ($sent) {
            echo 'Message Sent!';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'All Fields are required';
    }
    return;
}

/**
 * email function
 *
 * @return bool | void
 **/
function email($to, $from_mail, $from_name, $subject, $message) {
    $header = array();
    $header[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $header[] = "From: {$from_name}<{$from_mail}>";
    /* Set message content type HTML*/
    $header[] = "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
    $header[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";
    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $header))) return true;
}

?><script> 

    $(document).ready(function () {
    var form = $('#form'); // contact form
    var submit = $('#submit'); // submit button
    var alert = $('.alert'); // alert div for show alert message

    // form submit event
    form.on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit
        // sending ajax request through jQuery
        $.ajax({
            url: '', // form action url
            type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
            dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
            data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
            beforeSend: function () {
                alert.fadeOut();
                submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert.html(data).fadeIn(); // fade in response data
                form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
                submit.html('Send Email'); // reset submit button text
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems like there's no script tag in `?> $(document).ready(function () {` or was that left out?

Comment: That was left out, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Remove console.log(e), this is not recognize by IE

```
console.log(e)
```

Comment: Thanks. Sadly it still has the same problem however.